# Angular - Pass additional params to next component with route

Tags: angular, angular5, angular-routing, angular-router

I would like to know how to pass additional params to next page instead of using :id only.

**The current working code**

Origin Page (email-template)

```
addEmailTemplate(){
    this.router.navigate(['email-template','new','email-template-details']);

  }
```

Landing Page:

```
 this.route.params.forEach((urlParameters) => {
   this.emailId = urlParameters['id'];
 });
```

Defined route:

```
const routes: Routes = [
  {
    path: '',
    component: EmailTemplateComponent,
    data: {
      title: 'Email Template'
    }
  },
  {
    path: ':id/email-template-details',
    component: EmailTemplateDetailsComponent,
    children: [
      { path: '', redirectTo: 'email-template', pathMatch: 'full'},
      { path: '', component: EmailTemplateDetailsComponent, data: {title: 'Email Template Details'}}
    ]
  },
];
```

Imported router:

```
import { Router, ActivatedRoute, ParamMap } from '@angular/router';
```

**Things i want to achieve**

Origin Page (email-template), this code not working:

```
addEmailTemplate(){
    this.router.navigate([
       'email-template',
       {id:'new',type:'newType'},
       'email-template-details'
    ]);
  }
```

Landing Page (email-template-details):

```
I don know how to catch the "type" and "id". Expected to get "newType" from Origin Page
```

Answer (score 0):

You could use **route resolve**.

[route resolve](https://angular.io/api/router/Resolve)

Comment: Hi Franklin, can u give an example how to apply it? I am still rookie

Answer (score 0):

Sounds like a good use case for local storage.

```
addEmailTemplate(){
    localStorage.setItem('myData', JSON.stringify({id:'new',type:'newType'})
    this.router.navigate([yourUrl]);
}
```

Then on the page your routed to:

```
getData() {
  return localStorage.getItem(JSON.parse('myData'));
}
```